# I want to make a my own button which has 2 other button inside and I want to make them transparent but transparency doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, button, transparent, flowlayoutpanel

I have a button, I put 2 other buttons inside it. I want those 2 other buttons to only appear when I enter the main button with my mouse. When I enter it, I want the 2 other buttons to be half opaque and only be fully opaque when I enter one of those 2 buttons.

These buttons are inside a FlowLayoutPanel with a background image on it.
This is how they look like:

[image]

The Buttons have a picture inside them and a text.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | 
                 ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);

        Text = component.ProductsName;
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        Size = new Size(178, 75);

        foreach (Button item in CustomButtons())
        {
            Controls.Add(item);
        }
    }

    static Button[] CustomButtons()
    {
        Button delete = new Button();
        delete.Location = new Point(157, 1);
        delete.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        delete.MouseEnter += OnMouseEnter;
        delete.MouseLeave += DeleteOnMouseLeave;

        Button customize = new Button();
        customize.Location = new Point(delete.Left - 20, 1);
        customize.Size = new Size(20, 20);

        Button[] buttons = {delete, customize};
        return buttons;
    }

    private static void DeleteOnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button) sender;
        btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    private static void OnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button) sender;
        btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        btn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 
                                                       Color.Black);
    }
 }
```

I think I tried everything that came to my mind, I tried events and everything and the buttons never worked as I intended them to work.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :D

Comment: Did I get this correctly - you want the two buttons in the control to get visible when the mouse enters the parent button? -- Because I only see an EventHandler attached to one of the child buttons (the delete button).

Comment: Could you amend the question to state what specific issue you are running into?

Comment: @TimB Yeah, you got it correctly. Also when I enter the parent button, I want the 2 other buttons to be half opaque and only be fully opaque when I enter one of those 2 buttons, that's what I was experimenting with those EventHandlers

Comment: as this is highly visual, I suspect I can't help here. But as one programmer told me: First make your app work, and then optimize it. That means first attach a MouseEnter event for the parentbutton to make the two child buttons visible. Then experiment with opacity when mouse enters either of the childbuttons.

Comment: as for how to attach event handlers to the children, you could also use ParentButton.Controls[0].MouseEnter += ... (and [1] respectively), or do it wit foreach if you want it to be dynamic, not hardcoded.

Comment: @TimB Thank you, that's a good idea! :)
Any suggestions on how to make them transparent?

Comment: Forget about creating a composite control. Create a custom control and handle the paint.

Comment: As I said, I can't help with visual effects - I'm blind, so things like transparency etc. are beyond my league. But @RezaAghaei already helped me in the past, so I guess you' should follow the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems I solved it! I only had to set Flatstyle = FlatStyle.Flat and backColor = Color.Transparent! :D

Here is the result: [exsample of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWEzJ.gif)